# md-button not showing inside mdt-cell (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, material-design

**The code:**

```
<mdt-row ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <mdt-cell>{{task.id}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{task.title}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{task.actor}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell> <td><md-button>Edit</md-button></td>   </mdt-cell>
</mdt-row>
```

it shows 3 cell and other cell is empty. Even I can't click the cell.

I tried `<mdt-cell> <md-button>Edit</md-button>  </mdt-cell>` also.

I also used those but still empty. In inspect element console, shows no errors.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can use the attribute **`html-content="true"`** *(note: `mdt-cell` don't render HTML content by default)*.

So, your code should look like:

```
<mdt-row ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <mdt-cell>{{task.id}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{task.title}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{task.actor}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell html-content="true"> <td><md-button>Edit</md-button></td>   </mdt-cell>
</mdt-row>
```

You can see an official example [here](http://codepen.io/iamisti/pen/LGLYjZ).

Hope this helps!